# Python - Group Column values into Classes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I've a CSV with the following data:

```
Customer    Age
A           10
B           53
C           20
D            2
E           55
F           12
```

For that I'm using Pandas library to read the csv. My question is how I can group the Ages values in order to get a new column with intervals like this:

```
Customer    Age   Age_Interval
A           10      [0-10]
B           53      [50-60]
C           20      [10-20]
D           2       [0-10]
E           55      [50-60]
F           12      [10-20]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['Age_Interval'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=np.arange(0,110,10))
print (df)
  Customer  Age Age_Interval
0        A   10      (0, 10]
1        B   53     (50, 60]
2        C   20     (10, 20]
3        D    2      (0, 10]
4        E   55     (50, 60]
5        F   12     (10, 20]
```

---

```
b = np.arange(0,110,10)
l = [ "{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 10) for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
df['Age_Interval'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=b, labels=l)
print (df)
  Customer  Age Age_Interval
0        A   10         0-10
1        B   53        50-60
2        C   20        10-20
3        D    2         0-10
4        E   55        50-60
5        F   12        10-20
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
  Customer  Age
0        A   10
1        B   53
2        C   20
3        D    2
4        E   55
5        F   12
6        G    0

b = np.arange(0,110,10)
l = [ "{0}-{1}".format(i, i + 10) for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
df['Age_Interval'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=b, labels=l, include_lowest=True)
print (df)
  Customer  Age Age_Interval
0        A   10         0-10
1        B   53        50-60
2        C   20        10-20
3        D    2         0-10
4        E   55        50-60
5        F   12        10-20
6        G    0         0-10
```

Comment: One doubt: when my value Age is 0 then the Age_Interval get a Missing value. Why? How put that age at (0-10)?

Comment: @PedroAlves - need parameter `include_lowest=True`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
df['Age_Interval'] = pd.cut(df.Age, range(10,100,10), include_lowest=True)
```

Comment: thanks!!! One doubt: when my value Age is 0 then the Age_Interval get a Missing value. Why? How put that age at (0-10)?